# How to convert LaTeX equations to SVG?

Tags: command-line, latex

At the moment, I'm using `mimetex` to automatically convert a bunch of equations into gif-images.

The program is fast, but the images look pretty bad:

[image]

How can I (quickly) convert a LaTeX equation into an SVG image on the command line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*pdf2svg* works quite well.

Use *`\pagestyle{empty}`* to avoid page numbers and `pdfcrop` (package `texlive-extra-utils`) to remove empty space around the equations

Comment: That works well! It's a little bit slow, and I have a feeling I'm still not doing it quite right ([here's the script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/588760/) I'm using). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use pdflatex instead of latex, dvips and ps2pdf

Comment: It's no faster, but works pretty well. I'd really like a solution that does this job in under 100 ms, and preferably without writing a whole load of files, but it works and I'm happy. :-) [This is the result of your answer](http://paste.ubuntu.com/588779/) so far.

Comment: @Florian Diesch; the example link seems broken, can you remedy, perhaps embedding the example image?

Answer (score 9):

A new option is to use [`mathjax-node` from `npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-node). Install a distribution of node, then use `npm` to install [`mathjax-node`](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node):

```
$ npm install --global mathjax-node
```

Edit: You now have to install mathjax-node-cli, however, mathjax-node-cli doesn't show up (yet), so I had to pass the github repo:

```
$ npm install --global https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-node-cli.git
```

Once installed, you will be able to use `tex2svg`:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mathjax-node-cli/bin/tex2svg \
'\sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} = 1' > identity.svg
```

And the result:

[image: result of tex2svg, rasterized at 300dpi]

The generated SVG file renders properly inside a browser but [cannot be displayed using standard image tools](https://print-css.rocks/blog/2016-10-06/integrating-mathjax.html).

Comment: there is no `bin` in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mathjax-node/`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried **ekee**? It's a clone of LatexIt for Mac, it's great! It's hosted on http://rlehy.free.fr/.

[image]

Comment: `ekee` link says currently unmaintained. ... with last update circa 2008. [klatexformula](https://klatexformula.sourceforge.io/doc/formats) might be an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

[dvisvgm](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net) works quickly and nicely in my experience. It's in [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) 2010.